# Stop Bootstrap carousel when typing in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure that this is possible, but I suppose that it is.

I've done a carousel with a form inside. That form contains a textarea and a submit button.
So far, if the mouse pointer is inside the slider, it doesn't slide. Good for now. But if you keep the pointer outside the slider, they start sliding.

I would like to apply some javascript for that textarea, so when someone writes inside the textarea, the slider stops, even if you have the pointer inside or outside the slider.

This is my slider:

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
    <img src="img/iStock_dogSilverTabby.jpg" />
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h1>Licensed Veterinarians ready to answer your questions, 24 hours a day</h1>
    <p> 
    <form method="POST" action="1.php">
    <div class="row">
    <h3 style="padding-left:15px;">What is your question?</h3>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

            <textarea class="form-control" id="textareaquestion" name="textareaquestion" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" required></textarea>
            <span class="help-block pull-right" style="color:#fff;">0/250 characters.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit Question</button>
    </form></p>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
   </div>

    <!-- LINKED NAV -->
    <ol class="carousel-linked-nav pagination">
    <li class="active"><a href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
    </ol>
```

I hope you understood! Thanks for helping me! I hope this is possible!

Comment: Here's a starting-point fiddle. See if you can get your carousel working so we can see what's what. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/HBpEh/

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a method for this. You just need to invoke it on focus or click of your element. Something like:

```
$('input#textareaquestion').click(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
});
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: That's nice, I didn't knew about that! Thank you for the fast answer!

Comment: Without seeing your jQuery and the rest of your HTML it's hard to say anything. See the fiddle I posted on your question and fix it up, then we'll take a look.